# Генерация xml на основе словаря python

Tags: python, xml

Товарищи, помогите! :)
Второй день бьюсь и не могу решить проблему.

Мне необходимо создавать xml файл на основе данных из словаря python.
Данные которые потом будут в xml, берутся из БД. Данные из БД я получаю по названиям ключей самого словаря.
Я накидал пример моего кода:

Вот такого вида словарь

```
data_config = {
    'element_1': {
        'main_name': 'Элемент_1'
    },
    'element_2': {
        'main_name': 'Элемент_2',
        'element_2_1': {
            'main_name': 'Элемент_2_1',
        },
        'element_2_2': {
            'main_name': 'Элемент_2_2',
        },
        'element_2_3': {
            'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3',
            'element_2_3_1': {
                'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_1',
            },
            'element_2_3_2': {
                'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_2',
            },
            'element_2_3_3': {
                'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_3',
                'element_2_3_3_1': {
                    'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_3_1',
                },
                'element_2_3_3_2': {
                    'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_3_2',
                },
            }
        },
    },
}
```

Я хочу получить из него вот такой xml файл:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Файл>
  <Элемент_1>Данные</Элемент_1>
  <Элемент_2>
    <Элемент_2_1>Данные</Элемент_2_1>
    <Элемент_2_2>Данные</Элемент_2_2>
    <Элемент_2_3>
      <Элемент_2_3_1>Данные</Элемент_2_3_1>
      <Элемент_2_3_2>Данные</Элемент_2_3_2>
      <Элемент_2_3_3>
        <Элемент_2_3_3_1>Данные</Элемент_2_3_3_1>
        <Элемент_2_3_3_2>Данные</Элемент_2_3_3_2>
      </Элемент_2_3_3>
    </Элемент_2_3>
  </Элемент_2>
</Файл>
```

Моя проблема в том, что я не знаю, какая будет вложенность у словаря. Вложенность может быть любой. А так же есть элементы, которые одиночные и не имеют внутри себя других элементов. Я сделал код, который обрабатывает два первых уровня вложенности и использует списки вместо словарей, но мне необходимо использовать именно словари. Для генерации xml я использую библиотеку [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Вот кусок кода который я не дописал, чтобы был понятен ход мыслей:

```
def generate_doc(user_data: dict, required_data: dict):
    doc = Et.Element("Файл")
    required_data_keys = required_data.keys()
    for key in required_data_keys:
        current_doc_list = required_data[key]
        current_doc_name = current_doc_list['main_name']
        if len(required_data[key].keys()) == 1:
            Et.SubElement(doc, current_doc_name).text = user_data[key]
        else:
            current_doc = Et.SubElement(doc, current_doc_name)
    return doc
```

В user_data мне приходит словарь из БД без вложенности т.е. структура ровная.

```
user_data = {
    'element_1': 1,
    'element_2': 'Данные',
    'element_2_1': 'Данные',
    'element_2_3_3': 'Данные',
    'element_2_3_3_2': 'Данные'
}
```

В required_data Как раз тот самый словарь, который я разместил выше.

Вот таким образом я кладу данные в xml:

Et.SubElement(doc, current_doc_name).text = **user_data[key]**

user_data из ДБ, а ключ из ключа в required_data.

Как я понимаю, нужна рекурсия(но это не точно :)). Но у меня никак не выходит понять, как это реализовать.

Comment: Если это название элемента `'main_name': 'Элемент_1'` то где данные в словаре? или просто текстом "Данные" надо заполнить?

Comment: @alexjust 'Элемент_1' это будущее название тега. А данные для этого тега -- это обычный текст, который я получаю в словаре user_data по ключу, который является ключом для словаря required_data

Comment: А пример user_data можно?

Comment: @alexjust Добавил структуру в описание. Просто обычный ровный словарь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно в первом примере откуда берется текст "Данные", но для превращения словаря в xml (без учета наличия списка в исходном словаре) можно использовать такой код:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Xml

data_config = {
    'element_1': {
        'main_name': 'Элемент_1'
    },
    'element_2': {
        'main_name': 'Элемент_2',
        'element_2_1': {
            'main_name': 'Элемент_2_1',
        },
        'element_2_2': {
            'main_name': 'Элемент_2_2',
        },
        'element_2_3': {
            'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3',
            'element_2_3_1': {
                'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_1',
            },
            'element_2_3_2': {
                'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_2',
            },
            'element_2_3_3': {
                'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_3',
                'element_2_3_3_1': {
                    'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_3_1',
                },
                'element_2_3_3_2': {
                    'main_name': 'Элемент_2_3_3_2',
                },
            }
        },
    },
}


def get_xml_element_from_dict(data: dict, parent: Xml.Element) -> Xml.SubElement:
    for key, value in data.items():
        element = Xml.SubElement(parent, key)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            get_xml_element_from_dict(value, element)
        else:
            element.text = value


def get_xml_from_dict(data: dict) -> Xml.ElementTree:
    root = Xml.Element('Файл')
    get_xml_element_from_dict(data, root)
    tree = Xml.ElementTree(root)
    return tree


def write_tree_to_file(tree: Xml.ElementTree) -> None:
    with open('for_tests.xml', mode='wb') as file:
        tree.write(file, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)


result = get_xml_from_dict(data_config)
write_tree_to_file(result)
```

В результате получится такой файл:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Файл>
    <element_1>
        <main_name>Элемент_1</main_name>
    </element_1>
    <element_2>
        <main_name>Элемент_2</main_name>
        <element_2_1>
            <main_name>Элемент_2_1</main_name>
        </element_2_1>
        <element_2_2>
            <main_name>Элемент_2_2</main_name>
        </element_2_2>
        <element_2_3>
            <main_name>Элемент_2_3</main_name>
            <element_2_3_1>
                <main_name>Элемент_2_3_1</main_name>
            </element_2_3_1>
            <element_2_3_2>
                <main_name>Элемент_2_3_2</main_name>
            </element_2_3_2>
            <element_2_3_3>
                <main_name>Элемент_2_3_3</main_name>
                <element_2_3_3_1>
                    <main_name>Элемент_2_3_3_1</main_name>
                </element_2_3_3_1>
                <element_2_3_3_2>
                    <main_name>Элемент_2_3_3_2</main_name>
                </element_2_3_3_2>
            </element_2_3_3>
        </element_2_3>
    </element_2>
</Файл>
```